# It plagued/had plagued the reputation of him for the next seven years, which is right?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I read an article about Marie Antoinette on wikipedia and I found a sentence -**The couple's longtime failure to consummate the marriage plagued the reputations of both Louis-Auguste and Marie Antoinette for the next seven years**.

I am curious if it is right when I put '**had plagued**' in it instead of '**plagued**'. I guess that '**some affairs had plagued the reputation for seven years**' means there is another affair that restores their reputation after seven years from that failure.

Am I right? Also, If there is any ambiguity or errors on my post due to my bad english, please correct me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is correct as it stands. The writer is looking back on a period in history and reporting in the past tense.

As you surmise, to use the past perfect **had plagued** implies some other subsequent development. It probably, but not necessarily, points to something that either restores their reputations or overlooks them.

For example, it might read:

> The couple's longtime failure to consummate the marriage had plagued the reputations of both Louis-Auguste and Marie Antoinette for (the next seven) years but in time was overshadowed by their joint achievements.